# Problem with connecting Access to MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I have a problem with the connection of the Access database (client .mde file) to MS SQL server. After migrating the MS SQL 2000 database to the MS SQL 2008 client, the client can't access MS SQL.

The steps I use for connecting client Access are:
1. First I create a new connection in the ODBC Data Source Administrator
2. After that, in the Access client I enter the option ODBC and I link all the tables to the tables in appropriate database hosted on MS SQL 2008 server.

After launching the Access client , I was printing an error SQLSTATE 2800 SQLServer error 8456 login failed for user.

Do you know what the problem is and whether there may be a simpler solution for connection to the MS SQL server?

Also , i would like to mention, same user was working normal on previous version, and i am 100% that i am using correct credentials for user.

Comment: Have you consulted the logs on the SQL Server? If not, please do, if you have, what did you find? They will reveal reason for the login failure (such as incorrect password, unknown login, etc).

Comment: If you can't see anything in the logs, then that means the login attempt isn't reaching the SQL Server; so you'll want to check things like Firewall settings, connection strings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The below link looks similar to your problem. Kindly check

To resolve this problem, change the Server authentication from Windows Authentication mode to SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.

To change the authentication mode to SQL Server and Windows, follow these steps:

1. On the computer that is running Microsoft SQL Server, open SQL Server Management Studio 2005.

To open SQL Server Management Studio: 
a. Click Start, and then click All Programs. 
b. Point to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and then click SQL Server Management Studio. The Connect to Server window opens. 
c. In the Server name box, type the name of the instance of SQL Server. 
d. In the Authentication list, click Windows Authentication. 
e. Click Connect.

2. In the Object Explorer window pane, right-click the SQL Instance and select Properties.
3. Click Security under the select a page options.
4. Change Server Authentication to SQL Server and Windows Authentication and click ok.
5. Click ok to the prompt message about changes not taking affect until the instance is restarted.
6. Right-click the SQL Instance in the Object Explorer and select Restart.
7. Click Yes to restart the instance and if prompted to restart the SQL Server Agent.

After these changes have been applied and the SQL Instance has been restarted, attempt to verify the ODBC connection with the ‘sa’ account credentials.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2121736/error-message-when-you-try-to-authenticate-an-odbc-connection-to-your

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're posting a link please ensure that you include the relevant information from said web page. Links can become dead, making the answer unhelpful to future readers, and could attract downvotes. Link only answers are also flagged up in the review queues as low quality, and will often be deleted as result. Please take the time to improve your answer by including the relevant parts in your answer. Thanks.